# Django: <ul> inside help_text of field

Tags: html, django, django-forms

I would like to have a `<ul>` inside the `help_text` of a django form field.

Unfortunately django renders the `help_text` inside a `<span>`.

According to the HTML spec a `<span>` must not contain a `<ul>`. At least that is what my validation tool says.

Here is the source of django: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/forms.py#L283

```
def as_table(self):
    "Return this form rendered as HTML <tr>s -- excluding the <table></table>."
    return self._html_output(
        normal_row='<tr%(html_class_attr)s><th>%(label)s</th><td>%(errors)s%(field)s%(help_text)s</td></tr>',
        error_row='<tr><td colspan="2">%s</td></tr>',
        row_ender='</td></tr>',
        help_text_html='<br><span class="helptext">%s</span>',
        errors_on_separate_row=False)
```

What can I do to get `<ul>` in the `help_text` **and** valid html.

Overriding `as_table()` does not work, since the form is from "core_app" and the field is from a plugin. Both are two different git repos and I don't want to modify the core just because of this.

Comment: I think overriding `as_table` will help here (for the specific form you want this).

Comment: Or, don't use `as_table` at all and output your fields individually with the format you want.

Comment: @itzMEonTV overriding as_table() does not work. I updated the question. Thank your feedback.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I updated the question. The form is from core and the help_text is from a plugin....

Comment: I don't know how that affects my comment. As mentioned in the docs, `as_table` is purely a convenience method; if the output format is not suitable for your needs, don't use it.

Comment: If you're using `as_table` to render form, there is no other way than replacing it.

Comment: @DanielRoseman The plugin can't replace or avoid code from the core-application. And the core-application just uses django.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you already mentioned, in HTML there is a concept of **block** and **inline** elements.
In short block elements generate a new line and may contain other block and inline elements. Inline elements don't generate a new line and may contain other inline elements, but not block elements.

MDN web docs offers more information on [block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements) and [inline](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elements) elements.

Since `span` is an inline element, you can't place `ul` which is a block-level element inside. Or, you could, but then it's not a valid HTML, and that's not what you want.

Since you're using a third-party code, modifiying it could introduce other problems.
You could fork it, modify the parts you need and then use your fork. But when that third-party code gets updated, you have to repeat the whole process.

In cases like that you could just do [monkey patching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch).
For your particular problem we could therefore do something like this:

```
from django import forms

class MyBaseForm(forms.BaseForm):
    def as_table(self):
        "Return this form rendered as HTML s -- excluding the ."
        return self._html_output(
            normal_row='%(label)s%(errors)s%(field)s%(help_text)s',
            error_row='%s',
            row_ender='',
            help_text_html='<div class="helptext">%s</div>',
            errors_on_separate_row=False)

BaseForm.as_table = MyBaseForm.as_table
```

You can place this code in your `forms.py` or any other file that is suitable to you.

Now the `help_text` will be rendered as a `div` element, which is a block-level element. You can place an unordered list `ul` inside and have a valid HTML.

Monkey patching isn't the most beautiful way of solving problems, but it is in my opinion a pragmatic way to overcome some tricky issues.

Comment: In my case the field gets created in a plugin and the form is from the core (two different git repos). I could monkey patch the core from the plugin, but this could have unwanted side-effects. I guess I will ignore the html-validation in this case. Up to now I see no better solution.

Comment: @guettli I don't have insight into the core app and the plugin. Therefore I could write an answer based on the information provided in the question. Did you try my suggestion? I'd assume that monkey patching the `BaseForm` should affect the behaviour of third-party plugins.

Answer (score 5):

I think what you want is not exactly to "have an `<ul>` inside your `help_text`" but rather "display a bullet list inside your help text".

So if you don't have the ability to override `as_table()` or use something other than `as_table()`, I hope you are still able to change the stylesheet. In which case you can fake your `ul` with a `span`:

```
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

help_text=mark_safe(
    '<span class="fake-ul">'
    '<span class="fake-li">foo</span>'
    '<span class="fake-li">bar</span>'
    '</span>'
)
```

And here is your CSS:

```
.fake-ul {
  display: block;
  padding-left: 40px;
  list-style-type: disc;
}
.fake-li {
  display: list-item;
}
```

Comment: I like this idea too. It outsources everything to the CSS and doesn't mess with the Python code. I'd like just to add, that in order to be parsed properly, the value for `help_text` should be passed as an argument to `django.utils.safestring.mark_safe`. Otherwise the HTML tags will be converted to `&lt;` and `&gt;` respectively.

Answer (score 2):

So probably it is too late, but I think you may find [Django widget tweaks](https://github.com/jazzband/django-widget-tweaks) usefull.

Comment: I would upvote this answer, but it should include at least a minimal example.  In the present form it is a link-only answer.

Comment: Thats fair, i could add and example tomorrow